# Get JSONobjects from string

Tags: java, json

So i have a string which contains multiple JSONobjects and looks like this:

> [{"one":"1","two":"2","three":"3"},
>    {"one":"4","two":"5","three":"6"},
>    {"one":"7","two":"8","three":"9"}]

How can i iterate through this string using java and get every object? Is it possible using JSON api, or i should make parser by myself?

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GSON library](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) is a good option to convert java object to json string and vise versa.

- for converting json to java object use: [fromJson(String, Class)](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class))
- for converting java object to json string use: [toJson(Object)](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJson(java.lang.Object))

In your case it's a List of Object.

sample code:

```
class MyPOJO {
    private String one;
    private String two;
    private String three;
    // getter & setter
}

String jsonString = "[{\"one\":\"1\",\"two\":\"2\",\"three\":\"3\"}, {\"one\":\"4\",\"two\":\"5\",\"three\":\"6\"}, {\"one\":\"7\",\"two\":\"8\",\"three\":\"9\"}]";
Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<MyPOJO>>() {}.getType();
ArrayList<MyPOJO> obj = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, type);
System.out.println(new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(obj));
```

**Note:** The name of variable in your java POJO class should be same as JSON string.

[Find more examples...](http://www.javacreed.com/simple-gson-example/)

Answer (score 1):

You Should defiantly use the Json API, you can download the jar from [here](https://code.google.com/p/org-json-java/downloads/list) and simply use

```
JSONArray myArray = new JSONArray(yourString);
for (int i=0; i < myArray.length(); i++)
{
    JSONObject currentOb = myArray.get(i);
    doSomthing(currentOb);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious that you should use a JSON library. Existing libraries are tested and validated. In very rare conditions you may need to write your own parser, your own implementation. If that is the case, I think you should **double check** your design. Because you might be doing something wrong if the existing library is in conflict with your design.

Library selection depends on your environment and your performance requirements.
In my case, Spring3 is the environment and the JSON objects are huge (10-20MB), and inserts occur on existing JSON objects. We prefer [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/). Jackson's performance is outstanding. An independent performance comparison is in [here](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2009/02/entry_204.html). You will see that the Jackson outperforms GSon in [here](https://code.google.com/p/thrift-protobuf-compare/wiki/Benchmarking).